# How can we write two ngClass in one div?

Tags: angular, ng-class, angular-ng-class

Can we add two ng-class in one div?
If so then how to write it.
How can we write this together?

Thank you in advance.

```
<div [ngClass]={'white-background': policy number.length <=0}
[ngClass]="getSomeClass()">
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Furthermore, can't you write everything in one function something like: `<div [ngClass]="getSomeClass()">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class1': getClass1(), 'class2': getClass2()}">
</div>
```

With `getClass1()` and `getClass2()` returning `true` or `false` to conditionally apply class1, class2.

Comment: very interesting, always thought that was not possible

Comment: Here you'll find more about `[ngClass]`. Supports `ngClass: string | string[] | Set<string> | { [klass: string]: any; }`. https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
[ngClass]=['getSomeClass()', policyNumber.length<=0 ? 'white-background' : '']
```